# How does write ahead logging improve IO performance in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, database-performance, wal

I've been reading through the [WAL chapter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/wal.html) of the Postgres manual and was confused by a portion of the chapter:

> Using WAL results in a significantly reduced number of disk writes, because only the log file needs to be flushed to disk to guarantee that a transaction is committed, rather than every data file changed by the transaction.

How is it that continuous writing to WAL more performant than simply writing to the table/index data itself?

As I see it (forgetting for now the resiliency benefits of WAL) postgres need to complete two disk operations; first pg needs to commit to WAL on disk and then you'll still need to change the table data to be consistent with WAL. I'm sure there's a fundamental aspect of this I've misunderstood but it seems like adding an additional step between a client transaction and the and the final state of the table data couldn't actually increase overall performance. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are fundamentally right: the extra writes to the transaction log will per se not reduce the I/O load.

But a transaction will normally touch several files (tables, indexes etc.). If you force all these files out to storage (“sync”), you will incur more I/O load than if you sync just a single file.

Of course all these files will have to be written and sync'ed eventually (during a *checkpoint*), but often the same data are modified several times between two checkpoints, and then the corresponding files will have to be sync'ed only once.

Comment: _but often the same data are modified several times between two checkpoints, and then the corresponding files will have to be sync'ed only once._


Ah, excellent. I think that's where my misunderstanding came from. By waiting for a checkpoint you can make multiple changes to the same file rather than continuously retrieving the file and writing to it. Thank you for the clear and concise answer.